# passing the test result to testlink from soapui by groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui, testlink

I want to use SoapUI 5.0 to connect with a groovy script to the testlink server and then pass the test result to the test link

Before I tried to do this, I installed the TestLink Java API library downloaded from GitHub (https://github.com/kinow/testlink-java-api) as a jar file.

I copied the testlink-java-api-1.9.17-1 archive.jar to the directory with SoapUI the following paths: \SoapUI\lib and \SoapUI\bin\ext

```
//here is my code from the groovy script test step

    import testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIResults.*;
    import testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIClient.*;

     def DEVKEY="2f404203b306bd8dd811a7f824c194d0";
     def  URL="http://172.29.0.73/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php";

    TestLinkAPIClient api = new TestLinkAPIClient(DEVKEY, URL);
```

When running this script, the following unable to resolve class error occurs

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script74.groovy: 7: unable to resolve class TestLinkAPIClient @ line 7, column 19. TestLinkAPIClient api = new TestLinkAPIClient(DEVKEY, URL); ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class TestLinkAPIClient @ line 7, column 19. at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:146) at .......
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT6H8.jpg)

Is it possible in my case to connect using the groovy script from SoapUI to testlink?
And can anyone give an example of how to do it correctly?

Comment: Do you want to update the each test case to call TestLink and update? or Update all the test result at end of the test execution?

Comment: I want to add a groovy script test step to each test case, the results of which should be passed to the testlink. But first I need to deal with the connection to the testlink from soapui

Answer (score 1):

maybe someone will be useful.
It turned out to solve this problem in two ways:

1. Having analyzed the examples in the test link manual, I added the
   following code to a Groovy script test step:

   ```
   import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.Assertable.AssertionStatus
   import java.net.MalformedURLException;
   import java.net.URL;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Hashtable;
   import java.util.Map;

   import org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException;
   import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient;
   import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientConfigImpl;
   def TranId= "TranId : " + testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( "TranId" )
   def  Response= "Response: "+ testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( "Response" )
   def  TL_extid = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( "TL_extid" )
   def add_info = TranId +" " + Response;

   public class TestlinkAPIXMLRPCClient 
   {   
       // Substitute your Dev Key Here
       public static final String DEV_KEY =  "fcd38512b5c3e44befbc8b862e678894";
       // Substitute your Server URL Here
       public static final String SERVER_URL = "http://172.29.0.78/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php"; 

       /**
        * report test execution to TestLink API
        * 
        * @param int tcid
        * @param int tpid
        * @param String status
        */
       public static void testLinkReport(String tcid, int tpid,int bid,String plname, String status, String notes)
       {
           try 
           {
               XmlRpcClient rpcClient;
               XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config;

               config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
               config.setServerURL(new URL(SERVER_URL));
               rpcClient = new XmlRpcClient();
               rpcClient.setConfig(config);        

               ArrayList<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();
               Hashtable<String, Object> executionData = new Hashtable<String, Object>();              
               executionData.put("devKey", DEV_KEY);
               executionData.put("testcaseexternalid", tcid);
               executionData.put("testplanid", tpid);
               executionData.put("buildid", bid);
               executionData.put("platformname", plname);
               executionData.put("status", status);
               executionData.put("notes", notes);
               params.add(executionData);

               Object[] result = (Object[]) rpcClient.execute("tl.reportTCResult", params);

               // Typically you'd want to validate the result here and probably do something more useful with it
               System.out.println("Result was:\n");                
               for (int i=0; i< result.length; i++)
               {
                   Map item = (Map)result[i];
                   System.out.println("Keys: " + item.keySet().toString() + " values: " + item.values().toString());
               }
           }
           catch (MalformedURLException e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           catch (XmlRpcException e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
       //Send to testlink:
       //TestCaseID tcid, TestLpanID  tpid, BuildId bid, PlatformName plname,  status  ,notes

       TestlinkAPIXMLRPCClient.testLinkReport("$TL_extid", 7367,238 ,"FLORAWARE", "p",  
       "Result from  GROOVY SOAPUI $add_info");
   ```
2. I think the most elegant way.

in the soapui test project I`ve created a new rest service by specifying the path to the testlink api in the path to the resource with the testlink server address.
Like this:
[TestLink rest service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtcVX.jpg)

and then added the following REST request for passing parameters to the testlink:

```
<methodCall>
   <methodName>tl.reportTCResult</methodName>
   <params>
      <param>
         <value>
            <struct>
               <member>
                  <name>devKey</name>
                  <value>${#TestSuite#DEV_KEY}</value>
               </member>
               <member>
                  <name>status</name>
                  <value>${TL_Properties#TestResult}</value>
               </member>
               <member>
                  <name>buildid</name>
                  <value>
                     <i4>${TL_Properties#LatestBuildID}</i4>
                  </value>
               </member>
               <member>
                  <name>platformname</name>
                  <value>FLORAWARE</value>
               </member>
               <member>
                  <name>notes</name>
                  <value>TEST RUN FROM SOAPUI Transaction ID: ${TL_Properties#TranID} Response: ${TL_Properties#Response}</value>
               </member>
               <member>
                  <name>testplanid</name>
                  <value>
                     <i4>7367</i4>
                  </value>
               </member>
               <member>
                  <name>testcaseexternalid</name>
                  <value>${#TestCase#TL_extid}</value>
               </member>
                   <member>
                  <name>execduration</name>
                  <value>1</value>
               </member>
            </struct>
         </value>
      </param>
   </params>
</methodCall>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the library dinamically like this:

```
this.getClass().classLoader.addURL(new File(context.expand(project.resourceRoot) + "/libs/testlink.jar").toURL());
```

Or better yet, put all the dependencies in one jar file and use that script line. You have the use the decorated name of the class:

```
testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIClient api = new testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIClient(DEVKEY, URL);
```

This is about right 90% of the times.

Since Groovy and SoapUI are inconsistent, you may have to use two steps:

1. import the libraries dynamically
2. use the TestLinkAPIClient.

Once the classes are loaded, that error won't show up anymore.